# attach list workflow to another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I created a workflow attached to one list. I then set this list as a template and developed another list from this template. This lists are very similar but contain two different sets of information.

The workflow seems to have carried over to the second list. How can I do this again without the earlier steps? Both lists have the same field structure.

I am only a front end developer and don't have access to coding etc..., only SharePoint Designer. I'm also new at this!

Thanks,

Brent

Comment: Could you pls mention which version of SharePoint you're using and whether the mentioned scenario is in same site collection or different?

Comment: Thanks Arun, I 'm using SharePoint 2010 Foundation. The two lists mentioned are in the same site collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with SharePoint's Reusable Workflow. Reusable workflow can be attached to content type instead of specific list. So whenever you create new list based on that specific content type, the reusable workflow will be attached to it instead of creating new workflow every time.

Content type is nothing but collection of columns of a list/library.

Create new content type for your lists
[To create new content Type](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/creating-a-custom-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010-by-spike-xavier/)

Then you've to create list with new content type which you created
[To create attach content type to list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff630940(v=office.14).aspx)

Then Create Reusable workflow based on the new content type
[Create Reusable Workflow](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1095)